# convert the column of Movie id which has integer and character to integer value and convert back again in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

```
Heading
------------------------
5c7959ada58c402715002151
5c7958faa58c402715002129
5ba90b6dc1df413dae000431
5b8e5b32c1df41291800004c
5c628707a58c406b4d00001f
5c7958faa58c402715002129
5c62871ea58c406b38000266
5bfe8453c1df4108560012c9
5ba8d2d3c1df413dae00028b
5ba9f646c1df41479a0000cf
5c62871ea58c406b38000266
5ba90ae1c1df413dae00042b
```

Comment: is this a question or a task? :)

Comment: it is a question . i am using this for recommendation

Answer (score 0):

i used stringindexer from pyspark. it is working for me.

Any other solution would be appreciated